# Refresh an Archive Drive With a Mac

Tags: hard-drive, archiving

In order to verify the integrity and restore the magnetic strength of data stored on disks I use to archive data (intended to last 30 years or more), I want to read and re-write every block of data on the drive every year or two. Some are HFS+
and some are NFTS. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/880768/127149) suggests a utility that will do that when run from a Windows machine, but I don't have a Windows machine handy, and even if I did, I don't think the Windows utility will work with HFS+ disks.

I want to make sure that I am refreshing important "hidden" data like the partition map itself, so I'm looking for a procedure that I can run on a Mac that will simply treat the disk like raw block storage and just read and re-write each block on the disk, but at the same time provide enough information to call out which files are damaged if it encounters a read or write error. (Since I have 2 archive copies of everything, I hope I can recover a bad file on one archive with a good file from the other archive.)

I can think of a bunch of ways to read all the data on the disk if I can get the Mac to mount it as a raw drive, but no satisfactory way to write the data back to the same block or to identify which file a bad block belongs to.

A solution that re-writes the data would still be helpful even if it cannot flag which file is corrupted if a bad block is found. If you know of a solution that works only on Linux or Windows, I'd like to hear about it as long as it can handle both HFS+ and NTFS drives. Also, if you know of a utility that can determine which file a bad block is part of, given a raw block ID, that would be useful, too, as half of a two-part solution.

Answer (score 1):

First a remark : For long-term archiving, a hard disk is not the best medium.
Current [M-Disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-DISC) technology can keep your data [good for a thousand years](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2933478/storage/m-disc-optical-media-reviewed-your-data-good-for-a-thousand-years.html).
These discs used to be costly, but now their price has gone down.
For example, on Amazon [Verbatim M-Disc 5 Pack BD-R 25GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011PZAHTM) is currently $14.27
for a total of 125 GB. You will also need the right burner.
The advantage is that not much maintenance is required for the data after being
written.

Now about magnetic hard disks : Studies have shown that shelved disks lose
about 1% of their magnetism every year.
Although it would take more than 50 years to lose more than 50% of the magnetic
field, it is still advisable to do preventive refresh every 3-5 years.

It also turns out that modern disk drives will rewrite every sector whose
magnetic field has gone below a certain built-in threshold.
If the disk is left turned on long enough, every sector will be checked
by the firmware. If you don't wish to wait, all you need to do is force
a read of the entire disk (surface scan) for every sector to be verified.

Some commands that can read the whole disk are :

```
sudo cat /dev/rdisk0 > /dev/null
sudo badblocks -b 4096 -p 1 -c 32768 /dev/rdisk0
```

You should also keep an eye on the [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) statistics of the disk.
The Back Blaze article [Hard Drive SMART Stats](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-smart-stats/) lists
five S.M.A.R.T. metrics that indicate impending disk drive failure:

- SMART 5 – Reallocated_Sector_Count
- SMART 187 – Reported_Uncorrectable_Errors
- SMART 188 – Command_Timeout
- SMART 197 – Current_Pending_Sector_Count
- SMART 198 – Offline_Uncorrectable

Back Blaze uses as criteria metric 187 and recommends replacing the drive once
it becomes non-zero. However, other metrics are equally bad :
For example metric 197 counts unrecoverable sectors.
For archiving, I would say that it is preferable that all these metrics remain
at zero.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would need more than 100 M-Discs, and even then they would not preserve the directory structure, requiring a lengthy effort to reconstitute the drives should the project need to be revived, and then requiring a difficult and/or expensive effort to archive the project in its revised state. Also, `badblocks` is not present on my Mac. Do you have a reference to support your claim that "drives will rewrite every sector whose magnetic field has gone below a certain built-in threshold"? How can I confirm that my drives actually do that?

Comment: (1) [badblocks.c](https://searchcode.com/file/122236823/block/badblocks.c) and [badblocks.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/badblocks.h) is a very simple one-file program that you could compile and run. (2) M-Discs nowadays can go up to 100GB each. (3) Example article referring to disk refresh [is here](https://larryjordan.com/articles/technique-refreshing-hard-disk-storage/). To know if your drive does it would need info from the manufacturer.  You could also just `dd` the data off and back again on any kind of drive and any kind of disk.

Comment: On another possibility among many : The [Sony 1.5TB Write-Once Optical Disc Cartridg](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/983354-REG/sony_odc1500r_archive_cartridge_1500gb_write.html) ( $146) is "guaranteed 50+ years archive life".

Comment: "Sony 1.5TB Write-Once Optical Disc Cartridge" might be reasonably priced at around $150, but the cheapest drive I can find for it is $6,500, so it's not a viable option. And while the article you cite does claim disks refresh themselves, I suspect it's missing some important caveats, such as how the refresh is only done in the background to avoid performance degradation under heavy use, of which reading the whole drive as fast as possible would be a key example. I want to see something from a drive manufacturer or data recovery service. 100 GB M-Discs are even more $/GB than the 25 GB ones.

Comment: Archiving media is still costly, there is no way around it. As I said, cheap magnetic media is a possibility, but S.M.A.R.T. metrics have to be periodically checked. Such media should also be refreshed from time to time, even by such simple tools as `dd`, and replaced at the least indication of weakness. Opinions about the frequency for such maintenance vary from 2 to 10 years. Best safety is in keeping duplicates. Large hard disks of Enterprise quality are more rugged and not that costly, and you only need one, or 2 for duplicate.

Comment: And you should also be thinking about conserving equipment for reading. Nowadays disks use SATA, but would it be available 20-30 years from now? So you should also mothball a computer for reading them. But in 20-30 years, will that computer be able to communicate with modern networks if Ethernet will not exist any more? That's why investing in archiving media might be worth the price. The other possibility is to transfer the data to new modern media every decade or two. These are all long-term considerations needed to be considered now.