# 7zip archives become corrupted over time

Tags: hard-drive, 7-zip, archiving, file-corruption

I have dedicated HDD drive for storing data. To save space, I randomly over the period of last 5 years archived some folders with 7zip.

When recently I needed access to contents of these archives, after opening them, 7zip file manager told me that quite a few of them are corrupted. What could cause such massive corruption?

The drive is manufactured by Seagate, NTFS, healthy. I use antivirus and haven't suffered from viruses or ransomware.

Comment: You need to "refresh" the HDD content time to time (its needed because nature of HDD disc material). Use the tools suggested here: https://superuser.com/questions/514035/is-it-sufficient-to-refresh-an-archival-external-hdd-with-chkdsk

Comment: @uDev, I have to call FUD.  I've had drives hold data just fine for many years, and they also have error detecting code so if it did get corrupted, the drive would return an error, not bad data.

Comment: @psusi There's many type of drive (like WD AV edition) which are returns with bad data instead error/hang on bad sector. We should know the HDD model.

Comment: @uDev Seagate, 2TB, 7200rpm, Sata III, Barracuda (ST2000DM001).

Comment: @uDev, I think you are confusing returning bad data with TLER, where the drive returns an error quickly instead of futilely re-trying the read hundreds of times, taking several or even tens of seconds before giving up.